# R - TRUE/FALSE calling function not the same as step-by-step evaluation

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean

Working in R.

The goal is that by handing R a set of 8 numerical values that I get back TRUE or FALSE according to whether the line segment defined by the first 4 values intersects with the line segment defined by the final 4 values.

The input is in the form (x1,x2,y1,y2) for the first line segment
and  the same for the second line segment. This is a peculiarity of the storage system. The actual points of the line segment are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

So, for example:

```
do_line_segments_intersect(0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0)
```

should return TRUE because the line segment from (0,0) to (2,2) intersects the line segment from (0,2) to (2,0)

and

```
do_line_segments_intersect(-1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,1)
```

should return FALSE because the line segment from (-1,0) to (0,-1) does not intersect with the line segment from (0,0) to (1,1)

Here's the code that I'm using.

```
find_line_equation <- function(x1,x2,y1,y2)
  {
    A <- y1 - y2
    B <- x2 - x1
    C = A*x1 + B*y1
    return_list = list(A,B,C)
    return(return_list)
}
find_the_intersection_point <- function(list_1, list_2)
{
  coefficient_matrix = matrix(c(list_1[1], list_1[2], list_2[1],list_2[2]), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  coefficient_matrix <- as.numeric(coefficient_matrix)
  coefficient_matrix = matrix(coefficient_matrix, nrow =2, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
  RHS_matrix = matrix(c(list_1[3], list_2[3]), nrow = 2, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE)
  RHS_matrix <- as.numeric(RHS_matrix)
  RHS_matrix = matrix(RHS_matrix, nrow =2, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE)
  inverse_coefficient_matrix = solve(coefficient_matrix) 
    solution = inverse_coefficient_matrix %*% RHS_matrix
  return(solution)
}
do_line_segments_intersect <- function(ax1,ax2,ay1,ay2,bx1,bx2,by1,by2)
{
  a_coefficients <- find_line_equation(ax1,ax2,ay1,ay2)
  b_coefficients <- find_line_equation(bx1,bx2,by1,by2)
  intersection_point <- find_the_intersection_point(a_coefficients, b_coefficients)
  #find the boundaries of the line segments. This will let us check that our intersection is within the boundaries.
  max_x <- max(ax1,ax2)
  min_x <- min(ax1,ax2)
  max_y <- max(ay1,ay2)
  min_y <- min(ay1,ay2)
  #Is the intersection within the boundaries?
  if(findInterval(intersection_point[1],c(min_x,max_x)) && findInterval(intersection_point[2],c(min_y,max_y)))
    {
      print("true1")
    } else {
      print("false1")
    }
}
```

I know the code is not complete. My comparison to the max and min values should include all of the points (hence, coordinate values) rather than just half of them. And ultimately I want to return the actual boolean value rather than just a text string indicating what the value is.

The issue I'm having is the following:

If I run the code step by step on the input coordinates (-1,0,0,-1) for a_coefficients and (0,1,0,1) for b_coefficients and then run each line one-by-one then the final result is the "false" that I'm expecting.

However, if I call the function with the input like this

```
do_line_segments_intersect(-1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,1)
```

then R returns "true".

#### Why is it doing this?

#### And, more importantly, how do I fix it?

Comment: When you create `max_x`, `min_x`, `max_y`, `min_y`, shouldn't you call in anything from `bx1`, `bx2`, `by1`, `by2`?

Comment: It's planned implementation. I've simplified the code somewhat. I plan to add references to bx1, bx2, by1, and by2 later once I've resolved the issue at hand.

Comment: In the example you gave, `find_the_intersection_point()` returns a matrix of -0.5 and -0.5. The `if()` condition you have is therefore returning TRUE correctly. You mentioned that you should be returning FALSE, but I'm not seeing why.

Comment: That what was going wrong. I was comparing to only one line segment, and it was the wrong one. I needed to compare to all of the line segments as you pointed out. Thank you for helping me to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't comparing to the right values, and that was why my code was acting strangely.
Thank you, Phil, for help